# Installing amdgpu-pro ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amd-radeon, amd-graphics-card, linux-device-driver

Having issues installing amdgpu-pro for opencl support for applications like Davinci Resolve. I downloaded and ran the installer as stated on the website.

Version: amdgpu-pro-20.30-1109583-ubuntu-20.04

install succeed using the command: `./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=legacy,pal --headless`

However upon reboot, it seems that they are not being loaded:

```
dpkg -l amdgpu
dpkg-query: no packages found matching amdgpu
```

```
dpkg -l amdgpu-pro
dpkg-query: no packages found matching amdgpu-pro
```

```
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL vendor string" | cut -f2 -d":" | xargs
X.Org
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to what might be the issue here?

---

System info:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 
Host: MS-7B98 1.0 
Kernel: 5.4.0-42-generic 
Uptime: 1 hour, 20 mins 
Packages: 1801 (dpkg), 8 (snap) 
Shell: bash 5.0.17 
Resolution: 1920x1200 
DE: GNOME 
WM: Mutter 
WM Theme: Adwaita 
Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: gnome-terminal 
CPU: Intel i5-9600KF (6) @ 4.600GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI Radeon RX 470/480/570/5 
Memory: 1414MiB / 32052MiB
```

Comment: have you tried __sudo__ ./amdgpu-pro-install --opencl=legacy,pal --headless ??

Answer (score -1):

Your Ubuntu version is Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.
There is AMD Radeon's driver for that specific version.
You can check this :
https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-45